# How to add dynamic Facebook meta tags in GAE/GWT application

Tags: facebook, google-app-engine, gwt, guice

I've seen some techniques for doing this with other platforms but wonder if anyone has a clean way to do this.

My app has a single host HTML file and uses standard MVP/Places/Activities to parse a hash fragment. It displays a variety of like buttons for different elements. FB (confirmed using lint tool) will only read the static HTML of the host page so I need to manipulate that before it is returned to the requester (there is no point in messing around in GWT with this problem).

I use the Guice-y com.google.inject.servlet.ServletModule so I could create something like:

```
serve("/fb/*").with(MetaTagAdder.class);
```

And I could use /fb/* for the Like button urls. So spew out the HTML of the hosting page (adding in dynamic meta tags as needed). Then the *.nocache.js files just jump into the EntryPoint.OnModuleLoad().

This seems sort of clunky. Anyone have a more better idea?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up going this way and it works fine. Create a servlet whose doPost/doGet methods write out your host html and pass the parameters into it. So the url looks something like:

```
http://example.com/fb/mypage.html?foo=baz#place:foo=baz
```

Then you have the parameters available to create meta tags and so forth:

```
// the first chunk of the static html
resp.getWriter().println("<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\"/myMoodule/myModule.nocache.js\"></script>");

// the dynamic meta tags
resp.getWriter().println("<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"" + req.getParameter("foo") + "\" />");

// the rest of the static html
resp.getWriter().println("</head><body></body></html>");
```

Then when you are setting up the data-href attribute on your fb-like div, use the url above. Also works for SEO. Considerations for production systems:

- Navigation elements in the site should drive the user back to the straight hosted version. This can be tricky. Understand that you will have the query strings in the HTTP request remaining static while the hash fragment evolves to react to the user.
- If you have a limited range of parameters and do processing on the parameters, use memcache in the HttpServlet to cache semi-static copies of the html returned to clients.
- Don't be putting stuff in the body trying to get jazzy with your SEO. Heartache lies in that direction.

I'm still fooling around with tuning this but don't see any drop dead show stoppers at this point.